# DatePicker ignore values which are not in closedRange

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

How can I ignore/hide dates in a datePicker which are not in my closedRange?
The reason why I try to do this is because I think its more user friendly.

```swift
    var dateClosedRange: ClosedRange<Date> {

        let min = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day,
                                        value: 0,
                                        to: Date())!
        
        let max = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour,
                                        value: 48,
                                        to: Date())!
        return min...max
    }

    DatePicker(selection: $placemark.time,
               in: dateClosedRange,
               displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute],
               label: { Text("Reeve starts at: ") })
```

How to hide/ignore the marked area?
[image: How to hide/ignore the marked area?]

Comment: @JoakimDanielson nothing is wrong with my min and max. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I meant the properties in the DatePicker class for setting min and max